# How to save the content of a file in a list in Java?

Tags: java, list

I got two methods: `saveSubscribedFeeds()` and `loadSubscribedFeeds()`. In the save-method I'm saving some data to the file `feedsFile` in the parameter like this:

```
@Override
public void saveSubscribedFeeds(List<Feed> feeds, File feedsFile) {
    try {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(feedsFile));
        for (Feed feed : feeds) {
            pw.println(feed.getTitle());
            pw.println(feed.getDescription());
            pw.println(feed.getEntries());
            pw.println(feed.getUrl());
            pw.println(feed.getPublishedDateString());
        }
        pw.close();
     }
    catch(IOException i) {
        i.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

In the load-method I'm trying to load the exact same file `feedsFile` and return it as a List and for that I used a Scanner .

```
@Override
public List<Feed> loadSubscribedFeeds(File feedsFile) throws FileNotFoundException {    
    
    Scanner s = new Scanner(feedsFile.getAbsoluteFile());
    List<Feed> listFeed = new ArrayList<>();
    
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        listFeed.add(new Feed(s.nextLine()));
    }
    s.close();

    return listFeed;
}
```

However the JUnit-test is telling me that my list does't match the read object:

```
if (!feedsTemp.get(0).getUrl().equals(TEST_FEED_URL)
            || !feedsTemp.get(0).getTitle().equals(TEST_FEED_TITLE)
            || !feedsTemp.get(0).getDescription().equals(TEST_FEED_DESC)) {
        System.err.println("The data read from save-file '" + FEEDS_FILE.getName() + "' doesn't match the test input data!");
        fail("feed sample data (" + FEEDS_FILE.getAbsolutePath() + ") doesn't match read object!");
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Here's the Feed Class:

```
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.rometools.rome.feed.synd.SyndEntry;
import com.rometools.rome.feed.synd.SyndFeed;

import de.uk.java.feader.utils.FeaderUtils;

public class Feed implements Serializable, Comparable<Feed> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String url;
private String title;
private String description;
private String publishedDateString;
private List<Entry> entries;

public Feed() {
    
}

public Feed(String url) {
    super();
    this.url = url;
    this.entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    this.title = "";
    this.description = "";
    this.publishedDateString = "";
}

/**
 * Creates an instance of a Feed and transfers the feed
 * data form a SyndFeed object to the new instance.
 * @param url The URL string of this feed
 * @param sourceFeed The SyndFeed object holding the data for this feed instance
 */
public Feed(String url, SyndFeed sourceFeed) {
    this(url);
    setTitle(sourceFeed.getTitle());
    setDescription(sourceFeed.getDescription());
    
    if (sourceFeed.getPublishedDate() != null)
        setPublishedDateString(FeaderUtils.DATE_FORMAT.format(sourceFeed.getPublishedDate()));

    
    for (SyndEntry entryTemp : sourceFeed.getEntries()) {
        Entry entry = new Entry(entryTemp.getTitle());
        entry.setContent(entryTemp.getDescription().getValue());
        entry.setLinkUrl(entryTemp.getLink());
        entry.setParentFeedTitle(getTitle());
        if (entryTemp.getPublishedDate() != null) {
            entry.setPublishedDateString(FeaderUtils.DATE_FORMAT.format(entryTemp.getPublishedDate()));
        }
        addEntry(entry);
    }
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title != null ? title : "";
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description != null ? description : "";
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setPublishedDateString(String publishedDateString) {
    this.publishedDateString = publishedDateString != null ? publishedDateString : "";
}

public String getPublishedDateString() {
    return publishedDateString;
}

/**
 * Returns a short string containing a combination of meta data for this feed
 * @return info string
 */
public String getShortFeedInfo() {
    return getTitle() + " [" +
            getEntriesCount() + " entries]: " + 
            getDescription() +
            (getPublishedDateString() != null && getPublishedDateString().length() > 0
                ? " (updated " + getPublishedDateString() + ")"
                : "");
}

public void addEntry(Entry entry) {
    if (entry != null) entries.add(entry);
}

public List<Entry> getEntries() {
    return entries;
}

public int getEntriesCount() {
    return entries.size();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (obj instanceof Feed)
        && ((Feed)obj).getUrl().equals(url);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return url.hashCode();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return getTitle();
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Feed o) {
    return getPublishedDateString().compareTo(o.getPublishedDateString());
}
```

}

Comment: Where's the definition of `Feed`? Also, you write a feed by putting it's details into multiple lines but on reading a feed you read them line by line. How should the feed details match that?

Comment: Posted it now..

Comment: I don't see where you populate the title and description of your feed on reading them from a file, so how should they match the values in your test?

Comment: `pw.println(feed.getTitle());` creates a new line in the file with just the title. So your Feed object is written using 5 lines in the file. And when you read with `s.nextLine()`, you will first get the title, then the description etc.

Comment: How do I get the exact same content?

Comment: You are writing at least 5 lines in file for a single Feed Object and 
You are creating one object for each line from File. 
This is the mismatch

Comment: How do I avoid the mismatch?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: try using a debugger to see what's going on, when you run into such issues. You can progress in your code line by line and also see variables and their contents.
Second: The Problem you are facing there, as Tushar mentionend, you are writing title, description,... in a new line each time. Then when you try to read the object, you read just one line and then try to make a new Feed object, where you populate the fields title, description... with "" in the constructor and url with the given parameter. So what happens with the next line in the File which holds the description? It will generate a Feed object with the description set as url. Of course JUnit says, it is not the same object.
What you can do now:

- separate the fields by a constant character and break line only for a new Feed object. Then parse the fields from the separate lines to populate your objects. For example: url;title;description;publishedDate;\nurl2;title2;description2;publishedDate2;\n whereas the \n obviously marks the linebreak
- create an XML instead and use a proper parsing library. There are already java built-in libs you can use. Here's a link to a tutorial of one of them: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm